# Executing a python script from PHP to open a socket

Tags: php, python, permissions

I have a python script chatserver.py that includes:-

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory
from twisted.internet import reactor
<SNIP>
reactor.listenTCP(3800, factory)
print "Server Started"
reactor.run()
```

This opens a socket on port 3800 which works if I start from SSH but I want to do a check for the open port and if it is closed reopen using PHP but I cannot seem to get the python script to execute.

Here is how I am calling it via PHP at the moment

```
function serverCheck() {
   $host = "MYHOST";
   $port = 3800;
   $connection = @fsockopen($host, $port);

   if ( !is_resource($connection) ) { // port not open
       exec('/usr/bin/python PATH_TO_FILE/chatserver.py 2>&1');

    if($connection)
       fclose($connection);
}
```

I have tried a lot of things I have found on my searches but I just cannot seem to get the file to execute.

Comment: Comment: Since your `.py` file has the shebang, you don't need to explicitly tell bash to use `/usr/bin/python`. Just `chmod +x chatserver.py`

Comment: Did you make your python file executable with chmod -x?

Comment: Your `{` and `}` are mismatched!!

Comment: You're missing a close `}` on your `if`.

Comment: The file is executable yes (755). @JoeFrambach so I just use exec('python ./chatserver.py 2>&1');?

Comment: Since the file is executable, you can replace `exec('/usr/bin/python PATH_TO_FILE/chatserver.py 2>&1');` with `exec('PATH_TO_FILE/chatserver.py 2>&1');` for ease of use. But it won't fix your mismatched braces!

Comment: Is `PATH_TO_FILE` a const in php? Php constants aren't interpolated in strings.

Comment: @JoeFrambach = The closing bracket is in my file I just failed to type it here :)

Comment: @JoeFrambach no the full path is exec('/var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/chat/chatserver.py 2>&1');

Comment: What user is running your php script? What user/group does `chatserver.py` belong to?

Comment: @JoeFrambach user group is root

Comment: `ls -l chatserver.py` shows `root:root`? And I assume you're running the php script as `yourname:yourname`? That's your problem right there :)

Comment: Yes it shows as root:root. Any ideas how to make it run as root?

Comment: I'm writing up an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a permission issue. `chatserver.py` as it stands needs `root` user to run it.

Don't just `chmod 777 chatserver.py`. That is dangerous.

The way I like is to create a group for these administrative tasks:

```
groupadd chatserver
```

Then add yourself to that group:

```
usermod -a -G chatserver willroberts
```

Then change `chatserver.py` to be owned by that group:

```
chown root:chatserver chatserver.py
```

When php is run by your user, it will have the correct group membership to run the py file. This method allows more flexibility for more "chatserver" executables. Here's more reading if you're interested: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Users_and_Groups and http://www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_03_04.html

Comment: ok, so it now says the group is chatserver but still doesnt execute! The owner comes up as ftpn3wlog-n which is correct!

Comment: When you run `groups willroberts`, does it show you as a member of `chatserver`? When you run `ls -l phpscript.php`, is it owned by either `willroberts` or `chatserver`? And when you run `ls -l chatserver.py`, is it owned by group `chatserver`?

Comment: Or, is your `php` script run by a webserver? You can add the webserver user to the group `chatserver`.

Comment: Groups shows me in chatserver yes. The php file is still owned by root. Should I add that to chatserver too? This is the output I get for ls -l chatserver.py : -rwxr-xr-x 1 ftpn3wlog-n chatserver 1326 Apr  5 06:48 chatserver.py

Comment: Waiiiiit. How are you running the php script?

Comment: It is an API for an iPhone app I am working on so I am calling from the app. I have multiple other calls in there and they all get called and work from any user. The function 100% gets called.

Comment: Is apache running it? nginx? something else? Whatever user is running it needs to be added to the `chatserver` group. Perhaps the user is called `www-data` or something else. Run `ps aux | grep apache` or `ps aux | grep nginx` or whatever, to find out.

Comment: Output for the first one:     ps aux | grep apache
apache   24387  0.0  2.2  43140 20420 ?        S    Mar31   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   30481  0.1  3.5  59748 32236 ?        S    04:59   0:13 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   11989  0.3  3.4  60200 31644 ?        S    06:05   0:24 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    9518  0.2  3.3  59728 30960 ?        S    07:27   0:05 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    7294  0.2  3.3  59728 31040 ?        S    07:51   0:01 /usr/sbin/httpd
root     19865  0.0  0.0   1836   500 pts/1    S+   08:02   0:00 grep apache

Comment: The user is called `apache`. Add the user `apache` to the group `chatserver`, and change the `php` file to be owned by the `chatserver` group.

Comment: ok, so changing that meant I had to change some other files aswell as it was coming up with a ton of errors so now all of the associated files are owned by apache. API gets called but the python file still doesn't execute :( Thank you for this by the way, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Adding apache to a new group should not give any errors. That doesn't sound right. Anyway, run `groups apache` to be sure that the user `apache` is in the group `chatserver`.

Comment: The output of that was: apache : apache psaserv chatserver

Comment: Well then I'm getting a bit stumped. Let's back up and check for errors. In php, catch exec errors with: `exec('... chatserver.py ...',$output); var_dump($output);`

Comment: Another thing to check. If you're on shared hosting, make sure `exec` is enabled at all. `php -r "phpinfo();" | grep exec`. But I assume it is since you have root

Comment: ok so that prints out : 'array(0) {}' and hey, looking at the groups and owners of my files now I see that the group is chatserver but owner is apache. Is this correct?

Comment: Remove the ERROUT redirect from the exec call. Remove ` 2>&1` so the errors can be actually passed to php.

Comment: `php -r "phpinfo();" | grep exec` printed out a ton of stuff. What should I be looking for in there? Thanks again!

Comment: the 2>&1 stuff isnt there now since I changed to `exec('chatserver.py',$output); 
   var_dump($output);`

Comment: You should be looking for `safe_mode_exec_dir => no value => no value`.

Comment: This is starting to get beyond my knowledge. I suggest posting at http://serverfault.com/ There are more people there with this specific ability.

Comment: Should the exec path be full as in `exec('/var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/chat/chatserver.py',$output);` or just `exec('chatserver.py',$output);`?

Comment: Use the full path, Luke. Use the full path.

Comment: using system() I get 127 as the output and it seems no matter what I add the path to the file as it is the same. Something weird?

Comment: I have no idea what that means, sorry :(

Comment: that's cool. Any ideas how to debug this? If I can start printing errors that should help me get to the bottom of it!

Comment: Run `sudo - apache -c "/var/.../chatserver.py"` What does that do?

Comment: That will attempt to run your script as the apache user.

Comment: do I first SSH in as apache or when I am SSH'd as root?

Comment: So I added a hello world script to my server and changed the same owenership etc then ran from the browser. I get the following: Array ( [0] => sh: /var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/chat/helloworld.py: Permission denied ). Does that tell you anything?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is fixed :)

It was the shebang in the end :| I know.... I feel stupid!

It should have been #!/usr/bin/python but for some reason I had changed it thorugh various testing of things!

Thank you for your help in this. much appreciated!